# Sosl Returning Clause required

Tags: apex, sosl

Can anyone explain what is meant by this statement:

`The RETURNING clause is optional via the API, but required via Apex code.`

[SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm#sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax)

All I see from the docs is that the returning clause is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex Code requires it to reduce the amount of resources used by the SOSL call. It is optional for the API; in that case, it returns all instances found across all objects within the [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm).